# Searching for Shared Domain Documents using Google Drive API

Tags: javascript, google-drive-api

I have a set of documents which are shared out by a single user to all users in our domain. I am trying to find them via the javascript Drive v2 API like so:

```
  var request = gapi.client.drive.files.list({
    'q': "title='product-257961'"
  });
```

It doesn't find them. I have tried added other search (q) params like owners, &c. but nothing seems to find it.

I *can* find them using the web browser via a link like so:

```
https://drive.google.com/a/MY-DOMAIN/?tab=mo#advanced-search?q=product-257961&corpus=domain&view=2&visibility=2
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Did you ever a find a solution for this? I'm experiencing the same issue with the API.

Comment: Unfortunately, no. I think we need to wait until Google decides to expose this new feature via API. :|