# Google Drive API Files Search

Tags: javascript, google-drive-api

I need to create a file and share it for all user in the same domain within a JS application.

Here's the creation request body :

`{title: documentName, mimeType: "application/vnd.google-apps.spreadsheet"}`

Than I add domain permissions for created file.

Permissions' insert request body :

`{ "role": "writer","type": "domain","value": domain}`

**Result in Drive:**
[image]

Everything works fine for the user that created the file, I can find the file with `{q:"title='"+documentName+"' and trashed=false"}`.

But I can't find that file with another user.

I tried to look in sharedWithMe folder :

`{q:"title='"+that._documentName+"' and trashed=false  and sharedWithMe=true"}` **- no results**

I basically need to search like : [image]

But I can't find anything related to `source:domain` in Drive API's.

Comment: What does [tag:google-chrome-extension] have to do with this? Preemptively removing the tag, but feel free to add back if you can explain.

Comment: I think this question is attempting to solve the same problem, but it doesn't appear they have found an official answer either; other commentors saying the same: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20982992/searching-for-shared-domain-documents-using-google-drive-api

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I case someone still looking for this, ill post the answer.
The solution was quite simple, just needed to add query parameter `corpus` set to `DOMAIN`, something like this : `{q:"title='"+that._documentName+"' and trashed=false", corpus:"DOMAIN"}`

Answer (score 0):

I would try the following: set the owner of the file and remove sharedWithMe (after all it's explicitly shared with the domain, not with a particular user):

{q:"title='"+that._documentName+"' **and '" + owner + "' in owners** and trashed=false"}